# How to display arabic characters in web page using php and sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

How can I display Arabic characters in web page using php and sql server? The Arabic data is stored in the database (sql server). Now I want to use php to display that data on the web page. How can I do this?

Comment: HTML can display characters from any language. For example, this comment is displaying some arabic characters : ﲅﱗﮅٿجرﴊﻇﴆﶆﻸﴢ.

Comment: @Liao: "some" being the highlight there :P

Answer (score 2):

The official solution for Unicode in  mssql with php

```
$serverName = "MyServer";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"AdventureWorks", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

use this in your connection code,
get more support on utf 8 issue on 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626307.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Some SO archive may help you some ideas -

[Storing and displaying unicode string (हिन्दी) using PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-using-php-and-mysql)

[Arabic text displaying in webapp without db changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129808/arabic-text-displaying-in-webapp-without-db-changes)

[what is the best method to build "multilingual" script in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457586/what-is-the-best-method-to-build-multilingual-script-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Note: its php/mysql based example:

1. Before you can store Arabic content
   in a database, you need to create a
   table. The following example
   demonstrates the `CREATE` syntax
2. You need to make sure your browser supports the character set. `<meta
   http-equiv=”Content-Type”
   content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″>`

SQL Statements:

```
//assumed : connection to the database is open
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
// select records
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM en_authors");
```